# How to update Let's Encrypt SSL after changing domain A record?

Tags: cpanel

I am new to Cpanel and using CloudLinux 7.4.

When adding a new site to Cpanel a Lets encrypt SSL is created in the background which is great, however, I have an issue creating a site where the A records are not pointed to the server at the time of creating the site (for instance, I am setting up a site that is on another server and will point to the Linux server once ready).

The SSL is created but marked as self-signed which is logical since the IP can't be verified. How can I force the SSL to update after I have pointed the A records to the Linux server?

I am working on a large site currently using an SSL, I would like to avoid as much down-time as possible when transferring over.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

After much search I have ended finding out how to sort the above. Firstly, I was wrong about the type of SSL, it is not Let's Encrypt but Comodo but I don't think this makes any difference.

On my server the auto SSL is set to run at 3 am but if the change is urgent: go to WHM >> manage autoSSL. Under the manage users tab there is a blue bottom on the left of the user called check “username”. This sends the user back in the queue, in total in took a couple of minutes to update and the SSL is now fine.

I was originally looking at Cpanel site login and not WHM, little info on the subject on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended you to enable auto renew once the SSL expire, its will help you to keep the SSL active for your website.